# Svg icons not showing in vue project

Tags: vuejs2

I can't add svg icons to my navigation. I've tried doing
`` cssClass: require(`@/src/assets/med_icons/Icon_blood.svg) `` and still wont work. What I am doing incorrectly?

```
 ul.navbar-nav
          li.nav-item(v-for="navItem in navItems")
            router-link.nav-link.py-4.text-uppercase(:to="navItem.to")
              img(:src="navItem.cssClass")
```

```
 data() {
    return {
      navItems: [
        {
          to: { name: "dietPhaseDefault" },
          name: this.$t("mainNav.panel"),
          cssClass: `@/src/assets/med_icons/Icon_blood.svg`
        },
```

Comment: `navItems.cssClass` is undefined because its an array. Will it work if you write `img(:src="navItem[0].cssClass")` ?

Comment: Doesn't work this way

Comment: Sry to hear it. When it comes to svg's I personally prefer to work with`vue-svg-loader`: https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you mentioned that you tried using

```
cssClass: require(`@/src/assets/med_icons/Icon_blood.svg)
```

but here I see you have missed the end quote.

```
cssClass: require(`@/src/assets/med_icons/Icon_blood.svg`)
```

Please try this and see if your problem gets resolved else let me know.